# Multi Channel Voltage Buffer for BMS Testing

Tags: batteries, circuit-design

**Question**

I have a BMS slave with the LTC6811 battery monitoring IC on the bench.

Since I'm not that eager to test it with the battery stack immediately, I want to build a test jig and I need your help to figure out how to do that because I don't have the slightest idea besides a dozen independent / isolated voltage sources.

The circuitry should be able to be supplied by a single bench power supply with a maximum of 60 V (12 cells with 4.25 V max -> 51 V). It shall provide 12 voltage outputs where the voltage between the outputs should be adjustable via a potentiometer. Meaning pot 1 adjusts the voltage between out 1 and GND; pot 2 adjusts the voltage between out 2 and out 1 and so on. The following sketch illustrates this.

[image: Sketch]

The outputs should have fairly low output impedance. The jig will be used to test voltage monitoring and balancing with currents up to 300 mA which means that the outputs must be capable of sourcing and sinking current.

I'm looking for a schematic snippet that I can arrange twelve times to implement the required function in the best case but I'm also open for partial solutions.

Have a good one
Simon

---

**Solution attempt with parallel topology**

I came up with a solution where I put multiple OPA controlled power stages in parallel. The schematic below shows such a building block.

[image: Schematic parallel topology]

The power stages are supplied with 60 V and controlled by an OPA with level shifted output. The output voltage can be fed back with a voltage divider and I have an idea for reference voltage generation but I haven't worked it out yet.

The problem with this topology is that the output transistors burn a lot of power. This could certainly be tackled if I put the power stages in series - supply-wise - but I don't know how to supply the OPAs in this case.

I'm open for suggestions.

Comment: Do you have access to a bench power supply that can provide you with 60v (or a series of bench power supply that tally up to 60v)?

Comment: @SimonMarcoux I have access to a supply with four 15 V channels but would prefer to attach the jig to a single 60 V supply since I need one of the 15 V channels for the BMS master.